# TableViewCell doesn't show imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I added cell to my tableView and i want to show image in any cell i added an array of image to my class "MathViewController" and i want show these images in per cell.but no image show in any of cell.Do any one know about my problem? I'm very new to swift if you help me it will be great.
its my class MathTableViewCell to get the image from story board:

```
import UIKit
class MathTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCell: UIImageView!
}
```

and here is the class MathViewController:

```
import UIKit
class MathViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableController: UITableView!

    let items = ["Calculatorimg" , "ss"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableController.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MathTableViewCell")
        tableController.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableController.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableController.delegate = self
        tableController.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MathTableViewCell", for: indexPath)  as? MathTableViewCell{
            cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: items[indexPath.row])
            return cell

        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

and here is my storyboard as you cell identifier has been set to MathTableViewCell:
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1mYE.png)

Comment: These images are in assets or in the folder. If these imags are in the folder then you have to give extension of that image like "ss.png"

Comment: @jitendraModi they are in assets

Comment: just print items[indexPath.row] and what is output check it.

Comment: @nino have you created cell from storyboard?

Comment: Two notes: 1) **Never** register cells if you are using storyboard without extra nibs. 2) Remove the optional binding in `cellForRow` : `let cell = tableView.dequeue ...  indexPath)  as! MathTableViewCell` to exclude a design error.

Comment: @tusharSharma yes i did

Comment: @nino then there is no point to register cell in viewDidLoad() remove that line .  And even no need to redefine datasource and delegate in viewDidLoad() you might have done that in storyboard as well.

Comment: After the Edit: The Restoration ID is **not** the cell identifier! Is the cell **Identifier** in the Attributes Inspector (⌥⌘4) set properly?

Comment: @vadian thanx so much because of your attention i said I'm so new in swift but where is identifier

Comment: @vadian i added identifier and updated photo of storyboard but also same problem :(

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `cellForRow` and check if the image is created. Did you remove the `register` line and the optional binding in `cellForRow` as I suggested?

Comment: @vadian you are wonderful when i deleted registration code my problem solved thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Part 1: If create new Xib for cell.

Whole code is correct but forgot to register **UITableViewCell** Nib file into tableView.

Add below code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
tableController.register(UINib(nibName: "MathTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MathTableViewCell")
```

Part 2: Cross Verify **CellReuseIdentifier** is correct.

Comment: How do you know that the OP uses an extra nib?

Comment: i did it and i received an error : Could not load NIB in bundle with name 'MathTableViewCell'

Comment: is your **CellReuseIdentifier** = MathTableViewCell ?

Comment: There is no reason at all to use extra nib.

Comment: @vadian if new xib created for cell then it required to register cell nib file

Comment: The OP clearly does not use extra nib and – once again – *There is no reason at all to* do so.